# Did I mess up when plugging in values?

Tags: calculus, surface-integrals

To start, the question itself is:

2. Evaluate the Surface integral $\iint_S \mathbf F \cdot d \mathbf S$

---

B) $\mathbf F(x, y,z) = <z,x-z,y>$, S is the triangle with vertices $(1,0,0),\,(0,1,0)\,(0,0,1)$, oriented downwards.

I know the formula I'm supposed to be using is $\iint_S \mathbf F \cdot d \mathbf S = \iint_D (-Pg_x-Qg_y+R)dA$, where S is given by $z=g(x,y)$, and by finding the normal vector and solving for z, I've gotten that $z=1-x-y$. From there, I found S, which is $<x,y,1-x-y>$, with the domains $0\leq x \leq 1,\, 0\leq y\leq 1$.

for $(-Pg_x-Qg_y+R)$, I got $g_x=-1,\,g_y=-1$ and I plugged into the formula

$(1-x-y)(-1)\,-\,\bigl(x-\left(1-x-y\right)\Bigr)(-1)\,+\,y$

I simplified this to $x+y$, and plugged it into the integral, which became:

$\int_0^1\int_0^1x+y\,dxdy$

My final answer was $1$, however according to the answer sheet it's supposed to be $-\frac13$.

My guess is I messed up when plugging into the formula, but I don't know how. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is not in the values plugged in for the integrand, but in the bounds of the integral. Your surface is the plane $x+y+z=1$ for $x,y,z\geq0$. If we solve this equation at for $z$ and apply $z\geq0$, we get $1-x-y\geq0$, or $y\leq1-x$. Applying $0\leq y$ to this, we get $x\leq1$. Thus our integral should be:

$$\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}x+y\ {\rm d}y\,{\rm d}x$$

Which evaluates to $\frac{1}{3}$.

---

**Edit**:

You said the answer is supposed to be $-\frac{1}{3}$, not $\frac{1}{3}$. So there is some error in the integrand, and I believe it has to do with the "oriented downward" text of the problem statement.

In particular, you used $dS=\langle g_x,g_y,1\rangle$ in your solution. I believe that the "downward-facing" part of the problem indicates that the $z$-component of this vector should be negative, so it should be negative what you found, that is, $dS=\langle -g_x,-g_y,-1\rangle$.

This results in an integrand of $-x-y$, and an answer of $\frac{-1}{3}$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was wondering what could possibly have been wrong, but didn't think to check the integral bounds.